# Cloudformation template - how to make sure specific services are running after the EC2 instance is up

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I wrote a simple cloudformation template in JSON that brings up an EC2 instance from a pre-existing AMI. After the instance is up, I want to make sure specific services (SQL services) are up and running on that EC2 instance?

How can I do that in my Cloud formation template?

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation has `CreationPolicies` for that use case.

[CreationPolicy Attribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-creationpolicy.html)

Here you can define a "wait for a signal criteria" before the stack continues to create other resources.

For that signal, you need to implement a script on your EC2 instance, which checks for the needed resource a sends a signal if the check is successful.